# iOS - How can I click a UIButton behind UITableView with transparent header

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, clickable

I have a UIButton at the bottom layer of the UIViewController.
And I have a UITableView (full screen size) on top of the UIButton, the UITableView has a header (UIView) which has a transparent background which could be able to see through and show the UIButton.

The UIButton is not clickable even when the button appear behind the tableview header.

My tableView's cell and the header of the tableView has buttons on it, so I could not set `headerView.userInteraction = true` or `tableView.userInteraction = true`

I have tried to use `pointInside:withEvent:` and `hitTest:withEvent:`, UIButton is still not clickable in both cases.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: why are you not add the button inside the uiview which is in the header?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just add the button to the tableview's header?

Comment: I have a background image behind the tableView which will not be scrolled when tableView is scrolling. The button will stick with that background. This is why I put the button behind the tableView instead of putting it in the header.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UITapGestureRecognizer` for example like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    ... 
    let headerViewGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(MyClass.headerViewTap(_:)))
    headerView.addGestureRecognizer(mainViewGesture)
    ...
}

func headerViewTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Recognized
    { 
       let touchLocation = recognizer.locationInView(recognizer.view)
       print(touchLocation)
       if CGRectContainsPoint(myButton.frame, touchLocation) {
            print("button was touched")
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try **bringSubviewToFront** to get the button clickable.

```
       self.view.bringSubviewToFront(yourButtton)
```

Or you can check it in storyboard whether the button is inside some view, And add make sure the button is placed properly in storyboard. The button should be below the table view like in the sample picture.

[image: componets in viewcontroller]

You can try both the ways and let me know if you have any doubt.